# What's a good FTP client for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, software-rec, ftp

What's a good FTP client for Mac OS X?

So when you save, it should upload it automatically (like FireFTP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best by far is [CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch/) or the good old FileZilla

Answer (score 7):

I recommend [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) by Panic. I've tried a few clients and it's the one that offers the least problems (slow uploads, dropped connections…). It's not exactly cheap but the price is absolutely worth it.

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Flow](http://extendmac.com/flow/). It just feels very much part of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all of them (or at least all the ones mentioned here) and have come to the conclusion that none of them has the speed that [YummyFTP](http://www.yummysoftware.com/) can offer. It's also very customizable and easy to use.